# How does "npm run build" run the scripts in jquery github repo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Here is the [jQuery repo on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery). There is a "build" folder in jQuery repo. As the readme.md says the npm command:

```
npm run build
```

will trigger the execution of script in build folder and finish building process from many sub modules, which lots of js files. Is this correct?

There is also a command:

```
npm run test
```

It will run the test under the /test folder. I can understand from [npm document here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script), that "npm run" is short for "npm run-script".

**Question**:
There are many .js file under /test folder. How does "npm run test" invoke the lots of *.js files under "test" folder? What are the rules? Which file is the entry point? There is no "index.js"

I am asking this, because I also like to use "npm run test" on my project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `npm` commands are defined in [package.json](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/package.json) file at the root of any project. Check this part (lines 56-60):

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm install && grunt",
    "start": "grunt watch",
    "test": "grunt && grunt test"
},
```

So for the `test` script `node` will execute in

```
$ grunt && grunt test
```

Actually you can run that directly in CLI without `npm run test`:

```
$ grunt && grunt test
```

To see what that command does you need to learn about [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) and then check file [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) to see what exactly jQuery does register the `test` task .